# is dynamic allocation of arrays/cells bad in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I generally initialize and grow arrays and cells in Matlab like this:

```
A=[];
A=[A;[1 2 3]];
A=[A;[4 5 7]];

B={};
B{end+1}=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9];
B={B;[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]};
```

I have a doubt with this method. Is Matlab copying entire existing array/cell content to a newer location and making a new array? Simply asked, is this a bad way to do this? Or should i use pre-allocation like this:

```
A=ones(100,5);
B=cell(100,12);
```

And then update the array as i want. Is speed drastically reduced in former method or is it fine to use the former method. The former method is quite intuitive and comfortable to use. So is it good to continue with such programming style or switch to a smarter way?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html

Comment: `tl;dr` - Yes it's bad but there are some cases where it's unavoidable.